# Flutter Unable to render container

Tags: flutter, if-statement, flutter-getx, state-management

[image: This is ui]

I want to show the container with text but I am unable to render the Container. and the console didn't show any error.
Please help me
I am using Getx for state management.

```
Obx(
  () {
    if (controller
        .availableSlot[index]
        .slots.isEmpty) {
      return  Center(
        child: Text(
            'No Slots Available'),
      );
    } else {
      
    }
  },
);
```

json response

```
{"slot_type":"Evening","slots":[]},
```

I just want to show a text msg

Answer (score 0):

wrap with Container and color, and make sure you added expanded widget in about the container in case if you are using listview